# PowerShell script halts execution when Windows XP PC is locked

Tags: powershell

I have the following script that does a continuous ping and reports failures. It works fine, except the loop apparently "suspends" when the computer is locked. I have confirmed this by starting the script, immediately locking the PC, waiting 10 minutes, and seeing how many pings have occurred. It is nowhere near the expected number. What could be the culprit?

```
Write-Host "Entering monitoring loop..." -Background DarkRed

$ping   = new-object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping

$count_up  = 0
$count_dn  = 0
$count_dd  = 0

while ($true) {
    $result = $ping.send("10.1.1.1")

    if ($result.Status -eq "Success") {
        $count_up++
        $count_dd = 0
    }
    else {
        $count_dn++
        $count_dd++

        $this_date = Get-Date

        Write-Host "VPN ping failed at time " $this_date -Background Magenta

        if ($count_dd -gt 3) {
            Write-Host "***VPN is Down***" `a
            send_mail_notification("VPN is Down", "")
        }
    }

    if ($Host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable -and ("q" -eq $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("IncludeKeyUp,NoEcho").Character)) {
        Write-Host "Exiting monitoring loop..." -Background DarkRed
        break;
    }

    Start-Sleep -m 250
}

$total = $count_up + $count_dn
$uptime = 100 * $count_up / $total

Write-Host $count_up " out of " $total " pings for a " $uptime "% uptime."
```

Comment: If you intend to use this as a monitoring program why don't you just schedule it and let it run in the background, you can always come back and kill it later. That way it would run in its own context all together.

Comment: @BrentPabst I can do that, and that is the plan, but I was curious why this script would halt execution.

Comment: The problem lies somewhere in the IF statement with the RawUI stuff. Without that it loops fine when locked. You could use CTRL-C to break, but then you would lose your summary stats.

Comment: Curious as to your comment - you say after 10 mins of locked console, count is nowhere near what it should be.  Is it higher than a 3-4?  What is the number after your test?  Is it running but slowly? I wonder if the readkey is affected by the locked console.

Comment: @uSlackr Well for example if I immediately lock, and since the sleep time is 250 ms, after ten minutes I would expect 4 * 60 * 10 = at least 2400 as $total if I end script immediately. But instead I see $total is about 4 or 5, representing the time it took for me to lock and quit the program

Comment: Try commenting out the whole 'if ($Host.UI...)' statement to see if that clear it up.